# Are Windows 2003 Scheduled Task .job files compatible with Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

I have a large number of scheduled tasks we've like to move off a Windows 2003 server to a new Windows 2008 server.

I have a couple of questions

1. Can I just copy the `.job` files to the new server and reset the passwords?
2. If this is not possible, is there a way to turn each `.job` file into a user readable format, or even better, reverse engineer to a command line statement or script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I just copy the .job files to the
>   new server and reset the passwords?

No. Basically, the job files under Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 are of different format (binary vs. XML-based)

> If this is not possible, is there a
>   way to turn each .job file into a user
>   readable format, or even better,
>   reverse engineer to a command line
>   statement or script?

I know someone wrote a perl script to parse the binary data of Task Scheduler 1.0 job files into human-readable.
Take a look [here](http://windowsir.blogspot.com/2009/09/parsing-job-files.html).